# Как запустить программу с github на Linux?

Tags: github, kali-linux, x86-64

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить это https://github.com/AndreRH/hangover/ на Linux?
Kali Linux на arm64.

Comment: надо пройти по ссылке и внимательно читать все, что там написано. Прямо начиная с пункта 1.

Comment: Все программы собираются и запускаются по разному, и описание сборки описанно там же по ссылке в мануале. Уточните вопрос - что именно из того мануала у вас не получается.

Comment: @Mira сделал git clone и дальше не понимаю что с этим делать. Запустить нужную программу через Wine через терминал?

Comment: @DenKuzmin  Это не готовое приложение, его нельзя запустить. вам ниже в ответ скопировали текст из мануала к этой программе. Ее из исходников собрать сначала надо. Вы простите - вы если не знаете/не можете увидеть где мануал и не понимаете что в нем написанно, у вас недостаточный уровень для сборки самому, вам надо искать кто с вами по шагам это проделает.

Answer (score 2):

> To build this project you need:
>
> 1. The dependencies to build a 64 bit Wine (./configure --enable-win64)
> 2. The dependencies to build qemu (in particular glib)
> 3. x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (exactly this name)
> 4. i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (exactly this name)
> 5. About 5gb of disk space

1. Если wine не установлен, то установи его:
   `sudo apt-get install wine64 winetricks`
2. [Мануал по установке glibc](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Glibc-Install-HOWTO/) (начни с 3.1)
   Qemu:
   `sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm qemu virt-manager virt-viewer libvirt-bin`
3. gcc compiler: `sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 g++-mingw-w64-x86-64`
4. gcc compiler for i686 arch `sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64`

Comment: Wine точно надо? В readme wine сказано: "Don't forget to uninstall any conflicting previous Wine installation". Вроде как я и так делаю make install в директории wine

Comment: @DenKuzmin Ну да, если wine ранее не был установлен